# How to insert text into a textinput in kivy/KivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

How do you insert text into a TextInput. I cant figure this one out and have not found anything in the docs. I want text to appear in the text field

Answer (score 0):

Not the proper answer but here is a first idea:

print("Press Enter to continue")
enter_btn = input(" ")
if enter_btn in '':

## your code goes here

(I'm not working with Kivy, but I guess there is something similar there)

Comment: Sorry I found my example misleading so this answer does not got to do with it

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you're using `MDTextField`:

```
MDTextField:
        hint_text: "text"
```

Comment: Guys the question is how to enter text with a line of code and not to type it

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MDTextField;

```
MDTextField:
    text: "text"
```